# Default to adm group for upstart logs

Tags: configuration, upstart, rsyslog

This bug suggests that on 12.04, the default permissions for upstart logs do not allow rsyslogd to read them:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1074564

That is the logs need to be readable by group 'adm' (or is it 'syslog'?).  It's simple enough to change the group for any given log file, but how do I make it persistent such that any rotated or newly created logs get the right group?

Answer (score 1):

I only can answer about "rotated logs".

Change the last line of `/etc/logrotate.d/upstart` to read `create root adm` instead of `nocreate`, so that the file reads

```
/var/log/upstart/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 7
        compress
        notifempty
        create root adm
}
```

This tell logrotate to create a new file with the same name as the rotated one, to leave the permissions the same and to `chown` the file to `root:adm`.